# perl tk listbox, detect when focus is lost via mouse

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have two `listbox`es in a small perl/tk script. When I click on one, the other "loses focus" and the clicked one "gains" it. I put that in quotes because unfortunately these events do not trigger "`<FocusIn>`" or  "`<FocusOut>`". Using the keyboard, ie, the `tab` key, does trigger these. I have also tried `<Enter>`/`<Leave>` and `<B1-Enter>`/`<B1-Leave>` as well as `<<ListboxSelect>>` but none of these achieve what I need. I listed the available events to be triggered, but most are keyboard related.

What I need is to disable a `Button` when the second `ListBox` loses that focus (ie, when the first `ListBox` is clicked on), and enable it when it gains it via the mouse. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found an acceptable solution for this:

```
my $tmp = ref $my_listbox;
$my_listbox->bind($tmp, '<<ListboxSelect>>', sub { &listbox_bind; } );

sub listbox_bind
{
    my ($self) = @_;
    if ($self == $my_listbox)
        { $my_button->configure( -state => 'normal' ); }
    else
        { $my_button->configure( -state => 'disabled' ); }
}
```

hope that helps someone out there.